# Scala DSL with non-fixed set of value types

Tags: scala, dsl

I'm trying to design a DSL which is not fixed in the types it can support as values.

Below I try to achieve this with a `Value` typeclass. It doesn't have behaviour, though it would in the intended application.

```
trait Value[T]
object Value {
  implicit object IntIsValue extends Value[Int]
  implicit object StringIsValue extends Value[String]
}
```

The DSL consists of value terms and application terms:

```
abstract class Term[T: Value]
case class ValueTerm[T: Value](x: T) extends Term[T]
case class AppTerm[Arg: Value, T: Value](fun: Arg => T, arg: Term[Arg]) extends Term[T]
```

Evaluation function is where I have the compilation issue:

```
def eval[T: Value](term: Term[T]): T = {
  term match {
    case ValueTerm(x) => x
    case AppTerm(fun, arg) => fun(eval(arg)) // doesn't compile
  }
}
```

Here's the representative compilation error I get:

```
Error:(14, 40) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type A$A354.this.Value[Any]
    case AppTerm(fun, arg) => fun(eval(arg))
                                      ^
```

So the compiler thinks `arg` is `Term[Any]` and doesn't know it's an instance of `Value`.

I understand I can avoid it by removing `Value` constraint from `eval`. However, then I lose the behaviour of `Value`, I might want to use in `eval`:

```
def eval[T](term: Term[T]): T -- loses behaviour of Value typeclass
```

**So my questions would be**

1. why this doesn't compile, and
2. how to achieve something like this

---

Here's some usage of the DSL:

```
val i41: Term[Int] = ValueTerm(41)
val i42: Term[Int] = AppTerm(fun = (_: Int) + 1, arg = i41)
val theAnswer: Term[String] = AppTerm(fun = "The answer is " ++ (_: Int).toString, arg = i42)

eval(i41)
eval(i42)
eval(theAnswer)
```

Comment: I think path-dependent types are the answer here, since you'll lose the type information otherwise, as indicated by the `Any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the terms are carrying the necessary implicits with them but that way they are not automatically part of the implicit scope. A quick fix is to add a method to `AppTerm` that exposes the `Value[Arg]`. Then you can pass that to `eval` explicitly.

```
def eval[T: Value](term: Term[T]): T = {
  term match {
    case ValueTerm(x) => x
    case t @ AppTerm(fun, arg) => fun(eval(arg)(t.implicitArg))
  }
}
```

However, you might take this as a sign that you want to design your solution a little differently. For instance it seems dangerous that you capture the implicit `Value`s in the `Term`s and then in `eval` you pass in the `Term` and also again an implicit `Value`. So it's possible to pass in a different `Value` to `eval` than the one that got captured in the `Term`.